# Convert a decimal number into a byte size of 8 bit array

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 64
var_in_bin_format = bin(64)
print(var_in_bin_format)

#Output
#0b1000000

#Desired Output -- > should always be in 8 bit format
#0b01000000

def call_another_api(var_in_bin_format):
    pass
```

In Python, I need to call an API that expects its parameter to be always in 8 bit format regardless of the value of the decimal number?

I am not that good in bit manipulation so I am thinking if there is something I can do here?

How can I do this?  I cannot use the format() function as it will convert the value into a string representation and the API that I am calling will alert me that it is not in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you say that you can't use `format()` because it returns a string, I'm going to post this because that's also what `bin()` does. `bin(x)` is equivalent to `format(x, '#b')`. I'd guess that you haven't added the `'#'`, which means you won't have `'0b'` leading the value.

The [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) for `bin()` actually gives a pretty strong hint about how you might do this, using `format` instead.

If you know that the value passed will not be negative, you can use the format string `'#010b'`:

```
format(x, '#010b')
```

Breaking this down:

- `'b'` means that the number will be a string binary representation.
- `'10'` means that the entire string will be 10 characters long, two for '0b' and 8 for the value.
- `'0'` makes it pad with `'0'` instead of `' '`.
- `'#'` will add the `'0b'` prefix, as done by `bin()`.

Note that this assumes that the number is an integer in the range [0, 255]. Integers outside this range will generate valid representations, but will not match the format expected, and may have a leading `'-'`. Objects of type `float` can not be converted with the `'b'` format code. I assume that these are not problems, given what your intended output is, but it might be a good idea to add an explicit check to throw a `ValueError` if the value is less than 0 or greater than 255.

---

If you're in Python 3.6+, you could also use f-strings:

```
f'{x:#010b}'
```

Comment: I think this will not work.. the python API that I am calling is expecting an int... If we do the format part and send it as it is ....TypeError: Non-Int/Long value in arguments: b57eced0..  I somehow need a way to retain the values  as integer and require it to become 8 bits in length whatever the value is

Comment: You should provide some actual code. `bin` doesn't return a binary value, it returns a string. Please clarify in your question what you're actually trying to do. Computers already store numbers as binary, but there's no concept of the structure. There is no "format" for a number to make it binary. An integer is an integer. The value 0b1000000 is **identical** to 0x40 which is **identical** 64. Numbers aren't binary or hexadecimal or decimal, they're just numbers. They happen to be stored as binary in computers, but that doesn't change the number.

Comment: @MarkEstrada To be clear, there is no such thing as an integer with leading 0's, those only exist in representations.

Answer (score -1):

Is is not possible to convert all decimal numbers to 8 bit. You can only convert numbers from 0 to 255 in 8 bits.